# How to find the number of products sold on the same date they were created

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have two Google Sheets that auto update each week. One sheet contains Product IDs and their creation dates. The other sheet contains Product IDs and their sale dates.

Examples:

**Sheet One**

| Product ID | Creation Date |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Jan 1, 2023 |
| 2 | Jan 1, 2023 |
| 3 | Jan 1, 2023 |
| 4 | Jan 5, 2023 |
| 5 | Jan 5, 2023 |
| 6 | Jan 5, 2023 |

**Sheet Two**

| Product ID | Sale Date |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Jan 1, 2023 |
| 2 | Jan 1, 2023 |
| 3 | Jan 3, 2023 |
| 4 | Jan 5, 2023 |
| 5 | Jan 7, 2023 |
| 6 | Jan 7, 2023 |

I also have a third sheet where I've populated unique dates found in the first sheet using:

```
=UNIQUE('Tracking - Product Create Dates'!B2:B)
```

And another column where I total up the amount of products created on those unique dates:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(COUNTIF('Tracking - Product Create Dates'!B2:B,A2:A))
```

I'm now trying to create a third column where I total the amount of products sold on those unique dates, but that were also created on those unique dates. When solved, my third sheet would look like this:

**Sheet Three**

| Sale Date | Quantity Listed | Quantity Listed and Sold on Day 1 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Jan 1, 2023 | 3 | 2 |
| Jan 5, 2023 | 3 | 1 |

The reason I'm trying to do this is because I list a batch of unique items each week and need to keep up with the the percent of that batch that is sold at any given time. Eventually, I'd like to figure out the percentage of that batch that has sold over a week, two weeks, three weeks, etc., but figuring this out for one day would be great.

This is what I used to find my ALL TIME percentage of products that sold the same day they were created:

```
=SUM(ARRAYFORMULA(COUNTIFS('Tracking - Product Create Dates'!A2:A,'Tracking - Order Date'!A2:A,'Tracking - Product Create Dates'!B2:B,'Tracking - Order Date'!B2:B)))
```

I can't figure out how to filter this further. Please help.

Comment: If you want to show the quantity of products sold on any given date, you need to reference data that shows sales data - so far Sheets 1, 2 and 3 don't include any such data. You need to supply sample data for `Tracking - Order Date`.

Comment: @Tedinoz Hey, sorry for the confusion. Sale Date on sheet 2 is the order date. That's what I intended with that column title. Sheet one is representational of Tracking - Product Create Dates. Sheet two is representational of Tracking - Order Date.

Comment: `Sale Date on sheet 2 is the order date` Sure thing, but the data that you are trying to generate = `Quantity Listed and Sold on Day 1`. So where is the quantity data? Or perhaps/probably ;)  I've misunderstand what exactly, is the problem that you have.

Comment: @Tedinoz I see what you mean. All products are one-of-one. So every Product ID equals a quantity of 1 so every row on Sheet Two represents a sale of one product.

Comment: Regarding sheet2, could a product be sold on several dates during the month. For example, Product4 was sold on January 5. Could another unit of Product 4 be sold on, say, January 12?

Comment: @Tedinoz Good question. No because each product is unique. Each Product ID is only one unit. Once it sells once, it's sold out.

Comment: It would help if you could share a sample sheet with *realistic*-demo data and expected output(**manually entered**) so as for us to get a clear picture & workout a solution. You may also use the [**anonymous blank sheet maker**](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSeprZS3Al0n7JiVQIEiCi_Ad9FRXbpgB7x1-Wq6iAfdmVbWiA/viewform) provided by [*docs community forum*](https://support.google.com/) incase you do not wish to share a sheet from your google account.

Comment: @rockinfreakshow I'll go ahead and share a sample sheet later for sure and I'll also update my question to be a bit clearer.

Comment: Just for the record, the OP notes that there are blank sales from time to time, and products that had more than a quantity of one. The OP to update the sample data.